# Javascript Array doesn't map correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm "consolling" the entire code... but I can't find any issue, only a weird behaviour.

Let me explain:
I've an angular component (let's call it **parent**) which send some **tags** to his **child** through a **inputTags** array.
Then I need to set another list with ALL the tags of the user, called **allTags**.

The array (both **inputTags** and **allTags**) is formatted like this:
{ id: 'tagId', name: 'tagName' }

I need to make an unified array of those two. The expected output should contain an array of items that it's formatted like this: { id: 'tagId', name: 'tagName', selected: boolean }

In order to do this I'm mapping the **allTags** array in this way:

Let's suppose that:

```js
inputTags = [
    { id: 'work', name: 'Work' },
    { id: 'motivation', name: 'Motivation' }
];

allTags = [
    { id: 'network', name: 'Network' },
    { id: 'work', name: 'Work' },
    { id: 'smart', name: 'Smart' },
    { id: 'motivation', name: 'Motivation' }
];
```

Now... allTags are actually retrived from a server, so my code looks something like this:

```js
this.tagsService.getAll().subscribe(tags => {

    this.allTags = tags.map(tag => {
        let select = false;
        this.inputTags.forEach(inputTag => { select = (inputTag.id === tag.id) })
        return {
          id: tag.id,
          name: tag.name,
          selected: select,
        };      
    });

})
```

This for me seems quite standard, but in fact NO, because instead of getting:

```js
allTags = [
    { id: 'network', name: 'Network', selected: false },
    { id: 'work', name: 'Work', selected: true }, // is selected
    { id: 'smart', name: 'Smart', selected: false },
    { id: 'motivation', name: 'Motivation', selected: true } // is selected
];
```

I get this:

```js
allTags = [
    { id: 'network', name: 'Network', selected: false },
    { id: 'work', name: 'Work', selected: false }, // is NOT selected
    { id: 'smart', name: 'Smart', selected: false },
    { id: 'motivation', name: 'Motivation', selected: true } // is selected
];
```

Basically the issue is that it's selecting only one tag, not multiple tags.

Comment: The `.forEach()` is wrong. You'll get the result of the "id" comparison only for the last element in the list, because `select` is unconditionally updated every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
this.allTags = tags.map(tag => {
    return {
      id: tag.id,
      name: tag.name,
      selected: this.inputTags.some(inputTag => inputTag.id === tag.id)
    };      
});
```

Comment: It works thanks! Would it be better to use Santi Barbat reply, using "find()" and ternary operator, or yours?

Comment: @PietroLungarini both are corrects but this one is shorter

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Array map() Method

*)creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element and it calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order.

Note: `map()` Method does not execute the function for array elements without values and it does not change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
this.allTags = allTags.map(tag => ({
  id: tag.id,
  name: tag.name,
  selected: inputTags.some(i => i.id === tag.id),
}))
```

Comment: It works thanks! Would it be better to use Amadou Beye reply, using "some()", or yours?

Comment: A combination of both, using `some()` but without return as in mine :)